# Question about sharding

Tags: ether, scalability, sharding, white-paper

I'm reading the white paper, more specific about [scaling](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#scalability).

I'm stuck on the second strategy.

> Second and more importantly, however, we will include an
>   intermediate state tree root in the blockchain after processing each
>   transaction. Even if block validation is centralized, as long as one
>   honest verifying node exists, the centralization problem can be
>   circumvented via a verification protocol. If a miner publishes an
>   invalid block, that block must either be badly formatted, or the state
>   S[n] is incorrect. Since S[0] is known to be correct, there must be
>   some first state S[i] that is incorrect where S[i-1] is correct. The
>   verifying node would provide the index i, along with a "proof of
>   invalidity" consisting of the subset of Patricia tree nodes needing to
>   process APPLY(S[i-1],TX[i]) -> S[i]. Nodes would be able to use those
>   nodes to run that part of the computation, and see that the S[i]
>   generated does not match the S[i] provided.

Is this the same as [sharding](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ)?

Answer (score 0):

This is more similar to [Truebit](https://truebit.io/). Also, FMI see  https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ#how-does-plasma-state-channels-and-other-layer-2-technologies-fit-into-the-trilemma.